# I can't filter list term under admin/content

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I can't filter list term under admin/content.

There is not filter option for list term, just the types (taxonomy)

This is Drupal 7, ther is no category option.
[image]

This is Drupal 6, it can filter category.
[image]

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Installed Admin Views and add the following settings to /admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node/edit

[image]

But term list still not appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

admin/content page doesn't list taxonomy terms, it shows content nodes. Those options in the select list are actually Content Types you can filter by.

To view taxonomy terms, the link is admin/structure/taxonomy.

Anyway, in the remote case you do want to have better filtering options for nodes, I recommend the module [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views).

After enabling Admin Views module, you can go to /admin/structure/views/view/admin_views_node/edit to edit the view that's responsible for displaying the admin node list. Here you can add as many exposed filters you need, in your case, the term reference field.

Admin Views also requires Views Bulk Operations module which allows you to execute operations on multiple nodes at once.

Edit: Your taxonomy vocabulary filter needs to be exposed to appear in the form (click on the filter, then click on 'Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it'). Then all vocabularies should appear in the filter form.

Comment: Drupal 6 can filter the term but Drupal 7 can't. I just want to delete articles in bulk.

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: Drupal 7 doesn't support this out of the box, but if you install Admin Views, you will have access to the admin node list view and you can add any custom exposed filter you need, including the term reference field.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed the module and added term list but still won't come out. Question has been edited.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you need to expose your new filter(s).

Comment: The settings is already in it. The filter just can filter the vocabulary not term. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMSP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

One alternate way:

->You need to create a separate view for this.
->Add a expose filter for taxonomy term field.
->Add [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) (VBO) module.
->Delete the articles in bulk.

If you need more details for this process let me know.